# Does the PeerConnectionFactory and PeerConnection must be created and used inside a background thread?

Tags: java, android, webrtc

When I look at the demo `androidapp` in the unit `PeerConnectionClient.java` I notice that all actions connected to `PeerConnection` and `PeerConnectionFactory` are made inside `ExecutorService` (so as I understand inside a background thread). 
ex:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(() -> {
  PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(
      PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(appContext)
          .setFieldTrials(fieldTrials)
          .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
          .createInitializationOptions());
});
```

Why they use a background thread? Can we use the `PeerConnectionFactory/PeerConnection` inside the main UI thread? Is there any documentation about this somewhere?